# Unir 3 selects relacionados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero unir la suma de ciertos pero cuando hago el `select` se triplica al momento de hacer la consulta.

No entiendo la idea de porque se triplica pero debería salirme solo 7 registros ya que ese empleado tiene 7 registros nada mas .

```
SELECT DISTINCT(T1.personal_id),T1.periodo_id,
  T1.CTS, T2.EPS  ,T3.[REMUNERACION VACACIONAL]--,T4.[BONIFACION EXTRAODINARIA],T5.GRATIFICACIONES,T6.[HORA EXTRA 1],T7.[HORA EXTRA 2],T6.[HORA EXTRA 1]+T7.[HORA EXTRA 2] AS TOTAL_HORAS_EXTRAS
FROM
  ( SELECT D.personal_id,D.periodo_id,SUM(D.importe) AS CTS
   from Detalleboleta D
INNER JOIN Personal P ON  D.personal_id=P.PersonalID
where subconcepto_id=32 AND periodo_id BETWEEN 1 AND 7 and EmpresaID=5 AND D.personal_id=7
group by D.personal_id,D.importe,D.personal_id,D.periodo_id) T1
  Inner Join
  ( SELECT D.personal_id,D.periodo_id,SUM(D.importe) AS EPS
   from Detalleboleta D
INNER JOIN Personal P ON  D.personal_id=P.PersonalID
where subconcepto_id=18 AND periodo_id BETWEEN 1 AND 7 and EmpresaID=5 AND D.personal_id=7
group by D.personal_id,D.importe,D.personal_id,D.periodo_id) T2 ON T1.personal_id=T2.personal_id
Inner Join
  ( SELECT D.personal_id,D.periodo_id,SUM(D.importe) AS [REMUNERACION VACACIONAL]
   from Detalleboleta D
INNER JOIN Personal P ON  D.personal_id=P.PersonalID
where subconcepto_id=2 AND periodo_id BETWEEN 1 AND 7 and EmpresaID=5 AND D.personal_id=7
group by D.personal_id,D.importe,D.personal_id,D.periodo_id) T3 ON T1.personal_id=T3.personal_id AND T1.personal_id=T2.personal_id
```

SELECCIONANDO EL T1 Y T2 ME SALE BIEN PERO CUANDO QUIERO HACERLO CON EL T3
SE TRIPLICA LOS 7 CAMPOS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque sin datos de ejemplo no se logra comprender bien tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794).

Comment: HOLA VOY A SUBIR UN EJEMPLO CON UNA IMAGEN

Answer (score 0):

Para iniciar, tu agrupación está mal, estás incluyendo el importe que estás sumando y estás repitiendo la columna de personal.

En segundo lugar, te falta agregar a la condición del JOIN el periodo, de otra forma se multiplicarán las filas.

Por último, repetir una consulta casi identica para obtener diversos valores en las columnas es algo ineficiente y se puede hacer en una sola consulta mediante un agregado condicional (en inglés se conoce como cross tabs).

```
SELECT  D.personal_id,
        D.periodo_id,
        SUM( CASE WHEN subconcepto_id = 32 THEN D.importe END) AS CTS,
        SUM( CASE WHEN subconcepto_id = 18 THEN D.importe END) AS EPS,
        SUM( CASE WHEN subconcepto_id =  2 THEN D.importe END) AS [REMUNERACION VACACIONAL]
FROM Detalleboleta D
JOIN Personal      P ON  D.personal_id = P.PersonalID
WHERE subconcepto_id IN( 32, 18, 2) 
AND   periodo_id BETWEEN 1 AND 7 
AND   EmpresaID = 5 
AND   D.personal_id = 7
GROUP BY D.personal_id,
         D.periodo_id;
```

Por favor, siempre da formato a tu código. Será mucho más fácil de leer, entender y encontrar patrones que pueden agruparse.

Supongo que el resto de las columnas que tienes comentadas, serán sólo otros subconceptos que se deben sumar. Puedes seguir el ejemplo y sólo agregar las columnas.